# how to make connection pool in spring application using BasicDataSource

Tags: spring, struts

I have created the application in which I need to configure the connection pool.In which I am configuring the  connection pooling in  the spring_Config file. using the Basicdatasource.
but there is some problem to create the connection pool. Please tell me how to create the connection pooling in spring application using BasicDatasource.

I tried this one code in spring config ;-

bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
 
  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 
 
   jdbc:mysql:/revup?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/revup?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true</value>-->
 
 
    
</value>-->
 
   
  
</value>-->

```
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements">
    <value>true</value>
    </property>
     <property name="initialSize">
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property name="maxActive">
        <value>15</value>
    </property>
```

Is there any modification of code please tell me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Any details on a problem you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
<bean id="dataSourceApache" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coffee_shop" />
    <property name="username" value="john" />
    <property name="password" value="secret" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
</bean>
```

If you're using Eclipse, you should also download support for XML configuration syntax. It really helps you alot.

[SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts) has all the SpringSource support bundled ready for use.

Else, you can see all the fields that's possible to set in the [Java documentation](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html).